# Is the Past Perfect required in every case, where the action was competed before?

Tags: past-perfect, past-vs-past-perfect

I know that in English we can sometimes "skip" the Present Perfect and use the Past Simple, like here:

> *John has won the election*. Appropriate sort of the next day of the election night, when the speaker can suppose this is new information to the audience
>
> *John won the election*. Appropriate in other cases (when this is not new information etc.)
>
> *Have you heard me?* A more formal way, the result is important (we want to emphasize it), looks like a superior is asking a subordinate etc.
>
> *Did you hear me?* A more informal way, when the result is not so relevant (we do not want to emphasize it) etc.

Now, the question is:

Do the same rules apply to the past perfect, **is one forced to use the Past Perfect in every case, where the action was completed before the reference point?**

For instance:

> People had had no tooth disease, until they started to eat sugar.
>
> People had no tooth disease, until they started to eat sugar.
>
> I saw the car taxing from the garage, luckily the driver had managed to start the engine
>
> I saw the car taxing from the garage, luckily the driver managed to start the engine

This question is highly related to [that one](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/14059/how-to-use-the-past-perfect-tense-with-until), and the accepted answer there actually raised my doubts on the matter, because I have never heard that the Past Perfect can be "skipped".

Thank you very much.

Comment: Native speakers wouldn't normally say *Have you heard me?*, so if it *did* occur most of us would probably try to come up with some unusual *meaning* to go along with the unusual phrasing (for example, perhaps it's a lecture circuit speaker asking whether you've heard any of his previous speeches). There *might* be contexts where Past Perfect could actually be "preferred" in some of your examples - but to a first approximation they're all "unnecessary", and would probably be better expressed using Simple Past.

Comment: See [***FumbleFingers' Perfect Truism***](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/5666/32).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No speaker is *forced* to do anything.

Tenses add clarity to a statement with respect to the time(s) of the action.  Adverbial phrases do likewise.  Working together, verbs and adverbial phrases bring a kind of desirable redundancy to the communication. But the message can often "make it through" without such redundancy.

So both of these sentence are grammatical:

> Tooth decay was unknown until people began eating sugar.
>
> Tooth decay had been unknown until people began eating sugar.